# Is there a way to create a dual mesh using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry, procedural, bmesh, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a dual mesh, as [described by Alessandro Zomparelly](https://sketchesofcode.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/dual-meshes-in-blender/), but procedurally using Geometry Nodes. I've only come this far, but now I need to dissolve the vertices of the original mesh, before triangulation and subdivision:

[image: pre-dual mesh, vertices to remove]

I'm not sure it's even possible with Geometry Nodes, but it should eventually end up like this:

[image]

Then, of course, the edges need to be cleaned up, so that's another challenge.

Is there a way to achieve this in Blender? I'm using the latest 2.93 Beta.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there wasn't any way to currently do this in geometry nodes. This feature is still very new and the mesh manipulation nodes are limited.
In the meantime, if you want to be able to control a hex mesh using geometry nodes, perhaps (1) create the geometry you want in nodes, (2) create the hex mesh separately and (3) shrink-wrap the hex mesh onto your geometry.

Comment: i agree with Reinis. AFAIK this is not possible at the moment.

Comment: OK, thanks for the suggestions. I'll give that a go.

Comment: **Update**: As of todays date 15 December 2021, Blender 3.1 Alpha now has a Dual Mesh node

Comment: After 7 months!!!!!!! Cool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As someone mentioned in the comments, Blender now has a [Dual Mesh geometry node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/dual_mesh.html)!

It inverts the role of faces and vertices – every face turns into a vertex, and vertices turn into faces.

Combined with the Triangulate node on a rectangular grid mesh, it creates the desired hexagonal pattern:

[image: UV sphere, triangulated, dual mesh]

Choose the "Fixed" mode in the Triangulate node to make sure the direction of the triangles is consistent.

(I've extruded the edges to make them more clearly visible)

There is no need for subdividing and dissolving edges – this was a workaround to achieve the same effect.